# Get user-specific web-content

Tags: liferay, webcontent

I would like to ask if there is any Java API call in liferay which returns the web contents, which were uploaded by a specific user.

For example, I have one user who has upload some content and I want to show in a portlet this content, how can I do this via java?

Comment: You can use the search api to get all the user's content or extend the JournalArticleService to create a custom finder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are specifically talking about web-content which is displayed inside `Web-content Display` portlet, then you can use the `JournalArticleService` and `JournalArticleLocalService` API to fetch the content depending upon the User.
Prior to Liferay 6.0 Web-content was known as [`JournalArticle`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portlet/journal/model/impl/JournalArticleModelImpl.java#L73) and hence the API name has not changed.

So for example:

You can use `DynamicQuery` API, as follows:

```java
long userId = 10987L; // ofcourse you need to find this

DynamicQuery dynamicQuery = JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery();

dynamicQuery.add(RestrictionsFactoryUtil.eq("userId", userId));

int startOfList = 0;
int endOfList = 1000;
// if you want all the JournalArticle retrieved then use:
// int endOfList = QueryUtil.ALL_POS;

// this will retrieve the list of webcontents
List<JournalArticle> articles = (List<JournalArticle>) JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery(dynamicQuery, startOfList, endOfList);
```

The above code will retrieve all the `JournalArticle`s so you would get all the versions of a single web-content since all these versions are stored in the same `JournalArticle` table. So for this you can add conditions to the `dynamicQuery` for the fields like `version`, `id`, `resourcePrimKey`, `articleId`, `groupId`, `companyId` etc.

Or if you have more complex needs than you can create a [custom-sql-finder](http://kamalkantrajput.blogspot.in/2009/07/how-to-use-custom-sql-in-liferay.html) in liferay to fetch the desired data from any combination of Liferay DB tables.

---

If you are talking about contents as in Blogs, Wikis, Files, Webcontents etc then either use their respective `*LocalServiceUtil` or you can use `AssetEntryLocalServiceUtil` to fetch the assets for a particular User.

So with `AssetEntryLocalServiceUtil` also you can use the `DynamicQuery` API as shown above. The code may not be same but will be along the same lines.

---

You can know more about `DynamicQuery` API from this [blog](http://www.liferay.com/web/minhchau.dang/blog/-/blogs/using-the-dynamic-query-api).

Comment: @fchatzia That is gr8! Then will you be kind so as to accept this as an answer? You can tick the "check" sign below the voting option to accept this as an answer. Thanks